# Why does my Unity script not work properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I was trying to implement a moving system but there is an error that I don’t know what it means:

> Assets\moving_BEAN.cs(14,52): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

This is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moving_BEAN : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.getAxisRaw("Vertical");

        gameObject.transform.position = new vector2;

        transform.position.x + (h*speed);
        transform.position.y +(v * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a temporary variable for your vector 2. You need to create it with parentheses eg () because all c# works thst way. aet the x and y on thst temporary variable and then assign the position to that new variable.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a “syntax” error, and a usage error (or two depending on how you count it).

First, the syntax error is that you’ve missed the parentheses after creating a new struct.

BUT, for your use case, you probably don’t want to be doing this. What would make more sense is to get a copy of the transform’s current position, perform the calculations on that copy, before assigning the whole value back to the `transform.position` field.

```cs
var pos = transform.position;
pos.x += h * speed * Time.deltaTime;
pos.y += v * speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.position = pos;
```

Notice I also modified the position changes by `Time.deltaTime` so as to account for the frame rate.

The reason we have to work on a new copy of the position value is because `position` is a `struct` which is a “value” type. This is in contrast to a “reference” type, which you wouldn’t need to do this with.

Answer (score -1):

Here, on line 14, do this to fix it

```
gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(someFloatForX, someFloatForY);
```

Does your IDE give you red sqwiggly line? You can click the error to go to that line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First of all `transform.position` is a `Vector3`, You don't overwrite that to a `Vector3`.
Second, if You give a value to a variable like that, You close the `new ClassName` with `()`, so it looks like this: `Classname varname = new Classname()`.
Third, please provide more information regarding your problem. I cannot decide if this is a Unity3D project or 2D.
Fourth, You don't use things like this:

```c
transform.position.x + (h*speed);
transform.position.y +(v * speed);
```

You use ```+=`` and the whole /Vector3`:

```c
transform.position += new Vector3(h*speed, v * speed, 0);
```

And these 2 line are enough. You don't need the one line it gives the error.

Also, since you move the BEAN in an `Update()` method, which is frame-dependant, you should consider doing the following:

```c
transform.position.x += (h * speed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.position.y += (v * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

This way the bean will move consistently, not depending on the framerate.

Comment: `transform.position.x +=` doesn't work either since `transform.position` is a property that returns/takes a `Vector3` which is a `struct` => you can only retrieve or assign a complete `Vector3`

Comment: You are right, one sec